# 'No pages found' in Dashboard after registering custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

For some reason, none of my pages show up in the Dashboard after adding a custom taxonomy for a custom post type that I have.

This is happening only with Pages. Posts, custom post types, they're all there just fine.

Below is the code I used for the CPT, and the custom taxonomy.

CPT `career`

```
function career_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Careers', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Career', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Career Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Career:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Careers', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into career', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this career', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Careers list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Careers list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter careers list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Career', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Fields of career', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-nametag',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'career', $args );
}
```

Custom Taxonomy `fields`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'create_fields_taxonomy' ) ) {

    function create_fields_taxonomy() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Fields', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Field', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Field', 'text_domain' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
            'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
            'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
            'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
            'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'                     => $labels,
            'hierarchical'               => true,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'fields', array( 'career' ), $args );

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_fields_taxonomy', 0 );

}
```

When I try deleting the block of code for `fields` custom taxonomy, the Pages come back and they get listed in the Dashboard. So I'm quite sure it's the custom taxonomy that's the offending code here. Only that I'm stumped as to why.

Just an FYI. I've cycled through my plugins. I've even deleted them all just for kicks. No joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fields` is used internally by WordPress and can't be registered as a taxonomy or post type slug. Have a look at [the list of Reserved Terms on the `register_taxonomy` Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) for additional info.